# Is bathing/swimming without covering the whole body permitted for women?

Tags: practical-islam, women, culture

I know that in many cultures it's normal, for women, to cover up your whole body when you want to swim indoors, outdoors or just want to use the bathtub.
What I'm wondering about is if there's anything in the Quran, hadiths or the different judical houses in Islam that says that's how it's supposed to be?

Comment: When lonely under roofed baths, total covering is not necessary. But in Islam both men and women are highly recommended not to become totally naked while bathing even when no body sees them except themselves and Allah. As for swimming same rule applies provided that they are not in the sight of members of the opposite sex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is verse in Qur'an that talks about modesty

> And tell the **believing women** to reduce [some] of their vision and **guard their private parts** and **not expose their adornment** except that which [necessarily] appears thereof and to **wrap [a portion of] their headcovers over their chests** and **not expose their adornment** except to their husbands, their fathers, their husbands' fathers, their sons, their husbands' sons, their brothers, their brothers' sons, their sisters' sons, their women, that which their right hands possess, or those male attendants having no physical desire, or children who are not yet aware of the private aspects of women. And let them not stamp their feet to make known what they conceal of their adornment. And turn to Allah in repentance, all of you, O believers, that you might succeed. [An-Nūr 31](http://muflihun.com/24/31)

There is hadith that talks about going out with husband

> Narrated 'Aisha:
>
> Whenever the Prophet intended to proceed on a journey, he used to draw lots amongst his wives and would take the one upon whom the lot fell. Once, before setting out for Jihad, he drew lots amongst us and the lot came to me; so I went with the Prophet; and that happened after the revelation of the Verse Hijab (i.e. veiling). - [Sahih al-Bukhari Book 52, Hadith 130](http://muflihun.com/bukhari/52/130)

Not very detailed answer but you get the point :) and reference.

I did not bold list of mehram but that's understood.

Answer (score 0):

Islam does not allow women to show her body while swimming or bathing. There are many ahadith and verses of Quran that talk about women modesty. As Prophet Muhammad (PBUH) said: "If a woman reaches maturity and she don't cover herself then her prayers will not be accepted." A verse from Qur'an: And if have no shame remaining, then whatever you do, Allah is no longer concerned with you. I am not good at English. But I just tried to give you a concept through authentic references. I hope you would understand these easily. But if she is in private with no other men or *women* she doesn't have to cover her body.

Comment: Support your answers with ahadith and versus from the quran, and your approaching islam from an extreme view, women are suppose to cover awrat just like men do, but not in private property(Bath) where they are not exposed to other people. we all have to pee and poo does that mean we should do so in our own cloth, think logicaly, may allah guid you.

Answer (score -1):

For me I do bath naked
But I don't swim naked bc there is people
But if the swimming pool is at your house without any body in there I think its okay

Comment: Are your personal actions a source of Islamic law?